# Can I claim a post from my old deleted account?

Tags: support

I wrote this question and then deleted my account:

[What happened to Eric Ladd, illustrator of the 70s?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22926/what-happened-to-eric-ladd-illustrator-of-the-70s)

Now I have a different account. **Can I claim that question?** I'd like to chose the given answer.

Note: I have no idea what email address I used to register the deleted account and probably don't use it anymore.

Comment: Like most decisions, choosing to delete your account has consequences...

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I don't know. But, your best bet is to ask Stack Exchange employees directly by using the 'Contact Us' link that's at the bottom of every page.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered here: *[I  accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)*

Comment: The old account was deleted, so depending on how the backend is implemented there might not be anything to merge

Comment: Sorry, but your answer seems like you didn't even read my question. Or please explain how I can log into a deleted account.

Comment: I missed the 'deleted' bit, but the other end of that link states you need to login to either one of those accounts, so you can do it from your current one.